# Studying C++/CLI without prior knowledge of ANSI/ISO C++

Tags: c++-cli

I used to program in C#, and I want to study C++. Can I study C++/CLI directly before having prior knowledge of the ANSI/ISO C++?

Comment: It's not right question for SO (it's too opinion based). IMO if you're interested only in /CLI part...of course yes, as you can study Java without any prior knowledge of Python...

Comment: I wouldn't study C++/CLI if I had no good reason for this (such as developing wrappers for C++ classes).

Answer (score 5):

C++/CLI is a language that allows you to write pure managed code.  The compiler even has an option for that, `/clr:pure`.  But the code it generates then is not different from the code that the C# compiler generates.  There is therefore no point in using that feature, unless you are a die-hard C++ programmer that favors a C++-like syntax.

It is **not** equivalent to C++ and there's very little in the language that will prepare you to learn native C++.  Very basic native C++ constructs like multiple inheritance, RAII and *const* are either not available or only approximated.  Especially the new C++11 additions are not covered at all, not something you ever want to skip when you start out learning C++.

C++/CLI is targeted as an *interop language*, it makes it very easy to write a managed class wrapper around existing native C or C++ code.  Clearly that is no use to you either if you don't yet know what these languages look like.

Only consider using native C++ if that's the language you want to learn.  Learning C++/CLI will only confuse you.

Comment: +1: "C++/CLI is targeted as an interop language" neat.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but why?

If you want to learn about C++, you better start programming in C++ (without /Cli).

C++/Cli adds a set of complex behavior and managed pointer types that are not really useful outside of writing wrappers between C++ and C#, and ref classes lack some of the major benefits of C++; namely, RAII (deterministic destruction), const, and  templates.